# Statically-typed cross-OS Web platforms: Java, Mono, and what else?

Tags: java, .net, types, open-source

I appreciate this question may get closed due to its open-ended nature, but I'm curious none-the-less.

If I wanted to develop a cross-platform Web application using a statically-typed language, what would my choices be? I'm aware of Mono and Java, but what else is there?

*(When I say cross-platform, I mean Windows and at least one common flavour of Linux)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several high-performance Haskell web frameworks that emphasise strong static correctness:

- [snap](http://snapframework.com/)
- [yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/)
- [happstack](http://www.happstack.com/)

The goal is to lean on the type system to provide highly optimzied code, and zero chance of runtime failure.

To quote the Yesod web site:

> Turn runtime bugs into compile-time errors
>
> Yesod believes in the
>   philosophy of making the compiler your ally, not your enemy. We *use
>   the type system to enforce as much as possible*, from generating proper
>   links, to avoiding XSS attacks, to dealing with character encoding
>   issues. In general, if your code compiles, it works. And instead of
>   declaring types everywhere you let the compiler figure them out for
>   you with type inference.

Comment: These are completely new to me, thanks for the info! I am, however, sceptical about the 'zero runtime failure' remark - please could you elaborate on this? Static typing doesn't remove behavioural bugs...

Comment: I should clarify: The *goal* is to encode as many properties as possible in the type system, to approach zero possibility of runtime failure, in the limit. It doesn't mean you have a formally verified web app, but it is a step towards it.

Comment: Awesome, I'm currently using formal verification in .NET via Code Contracts. These sound like my kinda languages :)

Comment: On the more research end, there is a formal methods-approach to web apps, http://www.impredicative.com/ur/ - aiming at provably correct code.

Comment: Marked as answer for being the most informative/interesting (to me at least!). Plenty of other insightful answers though - thanks SO community! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use single language for the both client and server parts:

1. Java
2. C#
3. Google's Go
4. Scala
5. GWT(Java framework)
6. Haskell web frameworks

Comment: PHP and Python are not statically typed languages. So their frameworks do not prevent type errors at runtime from breaking the server.

Comment: You are mixing Frameworks and Languages. GWT is a framework that uses Java. This can be misleading IMHO.

Comment: @MikeMyers Oh, definitely upvoted for listing them all, but I just thought that the OP was pretty clear on wanting languages, not a list of frameworks that use the same language. The question does highlight the limited options of statically typed languages for web developers. Would be cool to see statically typed version of nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean statically typed, there isn't that much choice unfortunately. Google's [Go](http://golang.org/) language seems to begin growing into the web application space (there is Go support for Google's App Engine and projects such as [GoWeb](http://code.google.com/p/goweb/)), but these efforts are probably not very mature yet.

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) might be another possible option. While it also runs on the JVM, its web frameworks are very different due to the language's advanced features (see e.g. [Lift](http://liftweb.net/)) and might be worth a separate look.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Java and C# (via mono), you could also use (modern) C++ in the form of the
**[Wt (C++ Web Toolkit)](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)**.
Now the C backwards-compatibility part of C++ is not strongly typed, but otherwise C++ programs are type safe.

If you want really strong type safety, you can use Haskell with **[Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/)**. The goal of Yesod is to use strong types to prevent common errors in programming web applications. URLs, for instance, are type checked. You cannot construct an intra-application link without supplying the correct parameters. Escaping of user-content when rendering the web page is another situation where the Haskell compiler is used to ensure that strings are properly escaped before being included in a rendered page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) is stongly typed, so [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) be a good choice for this.

Comment: Are you sure Ruby is strongly typed? Wikipedia seems to think otherwise...

Comment: Yes, but ruby is not **statically typed**. Strongly typed means that the programming system rejects expressions/operations where the types don't match up. But this might be enforced at runtime, such as in Ruby.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks for cleaning that up. I shall update the question!